# VS15 Include Path

Tags: visual-studio-2015, include-path

I work on a project in VS15 which is stored like this:

```
Projectmap
- Project_A
- Project_B
- Project_C
```

Inside of each project the include path looks like this:

```
#include "./Project_A/Folder/file.h"
```

Visual Studio is unable to follow the given path. I tried adding to the include path in settings $(SolutionDir) and $(ProjectDir) but both didn't work.

How can I use the include path?

Comment: Paths are relative to **project** root dir by default. The above statement won't work, as it needs to move up one folder if in project other than _Project\_A_, or it tries to go to _Project\_A_ twice otherwise. The above statement should be modified to: `#include "../Project_A/Folder/file.h"` (if in _Project\_A_ you could use the shortcut: `#include "Folder/file.h"`), or set the include path to `$(SolutionDir)` (_Projectmap_ dir) (for **every** project), and `#include "Project_A/Folder/file.h"`. Same thing for lib folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out, how to solve this problem.

It's close to CristiFati. I had to add

```
$(SolutionDir)
```

After that point I could use

```
#include "./Project_A/Folder/file.h"
```

I could also use the path without ./ but it was used in the project many times and I don't want to change much there...

Thanks for the advice :)